# How to get the string value of an HTTP header that I just set in Go?

Tags: http, go

I have the following mind-blowingly simple Go code.

```
 package main
 
 import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
 )
 func main() {
    h := http.Header{
        "my_id": []string{"XYZ"},
    }
     fmt.Println("h.Get(\"my_id\") = ", h.Get("my_id"))
 }
```

But when I run it it doesn't work as expected, Here is the output:

```
h.Get("my_id") =
```

Why can't I print out the value of the header I *just* set?

Here is the live code for you to see yourself: https://play.golang.org/p/L45LzVqd341

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Header.Get` uses `http.CanonicalHeaderKey` to lookup keys. If you use `h.Set` or put `My_id`, it will work.

This is explained in `Header.Get` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the Headers are just a `map[string][]string`. So you can always get access to them by simply

```
if myID, ok := h["my_id"]; ok {
    fmt.Println("myID", myID)
} else {
    fmt.Println("my_id header not found")
}
```